# Retrieved Data Not Displayed in Textviews

Tags: java, android, textview, json, request-queueing

I am a beginner for Java Coding and is currently coding an Android Project. Right now, I am facing an issue. The data retrieved is not showing up in the textviews.

My plan is to retrieve the details using the vehicle number from the intent. After which, the details will be shown in the textviews. I've checked, the php is showing the information i need, which means that it is the java that is having problem. However, i'm unable to spot the mistake. Please advice me or provide me with some examples. Thank you.

```
package com.example.maptesting;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class NextActivity extends Activity {

TextView vehicle_no;
TextView resultSessionID;
TextView resultPartial;

RequestQueue requestQueue;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);


    vehicle_no = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vehicle_no);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String veh_no = intent.getStringExtra("vehicleno");
    vehicle_no.setText(veh_no);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    String url = ("http://mp60.bas-mp.bus/testingtesting/showPartialDetails.php?vehicle_no=" + vehicle_no.getText().toString());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray students = response.getJSONArray("students");
                for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject parkingsession = students.getJSONObject(i);

                    String parkingsession_id = parkingsession.getString("parkingsession_id");

                    String datetime_start = parkingsession.getString("datetime_start");
                    String datetime_end = parkingsession.getString("datetime_end");
                    String duration = parkingsession.getString("duration");
                    String charges = parkingsession.getString("charges");

                    resultSessionID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.parkingsessionID);
                    resultSessionID.append(parkingsession_id);

                    resultPartial = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details1);
                    resultPartial.append("Session Start:"  + datetime_start + "\n"+
                                    "Session End:" + datetime_end + "\n"+
                                    "Duration:" + duration + "\n"+
                                    "Total Charges:" + charges + "\n");
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}




}
```

Comment: Try to change this resultPartial.append to resultPartial.setText

Comment: @ajantha hello, i just tried. it doesn't work. ):

Comment: try debugging your app and check if you are getting a value for vehicle_no here String url = ("http://mp60.bas-mp.bus/testingtesting/showPartialDetails.php?vehicle_no=" + vehicle_no.getText().toString());

Comment: @ajantha yep. it is being sent.

Comment: @redblackwhite try my updated answer

Comment: print the response in log and check if the keys you are using exists in response or not.

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of using append like

```
  resultSessionID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.parkingsessionID);
                    resultSessionID.append(parkingsession_id);

                    resultPartial = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details1);
                    resultPartial.append("Session Start:"  + datetime_start + "\n"+
                                    "Session End:" + datetime_end + "\n"+
                                    "Duration:" + duration + "\n"+
                                    "Total Charges:" + charges + "\n");
```

> use set text

```
 resultSessionID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.parkingsessionID);
                    resultSessionID.setText(parkingsession_id);

                    resultPartial = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details1);
                    resultPartial.setText("Session Start:"  + datetime_start + "\n"+
                                    "Session End:" + datetime_end + "\n"+
                                    "Duration:" + duration + "\n"+
                                    "Total Charges:" + charges + "\n");
```

> try sending the data i.e your vehicle_no as a map value.So pass updateVehicleInfo() vehicle_no that you get as a intent extra.

```
 public void updateVehicleInfo(final String veh_number)
    {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Update Response"+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(KEY_VEHICLENO, veh_number);

                 return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

Comment: try debugging your app and check if the vehicle number is being sent or not also Log your response or try toasting the response from your php code.

Comment: yep. it is being sent.